# Wingpanel crashing after upgrade

Tags: wingpanel, system

After my recent upgrade (`apt-get dist-upgrade && apt-get upgrade -y`), my wing panel disappeared after crashing and reappearing several times. Calling to the command line gives :

```
[ERROR 14:00:40.293329] [GLib-GIO] Settings schema 'org.pantheon.desktop.slingshot' does not contain a key named 'show-category-filter'
```

The whole command line output being :

```
[INFO 14:00:25.783136] Application.vala:153: System Panel version: 2.0.4
[INFO 14:00:25.783295] Application.vala:155: Kernel version: 4.4.0-116-generic
[FATAL 14:00:28.991514] [AccountsService] act_user_get_uid: assertion 'ACT_IS_USER (user)' failed
[FATAL 14:00:29.010746] [AccountsService] act_user_get_uid: assertion 'ACT_IS_USER (user)' failed
[FATAL 14:00:29.040781] display_widget_set_icon_name: assertion 'self != NULL' failed
[FATAL 14:00:29.041774] display_widget_set_icon_name: assertion 'self != NULL' failed
[FATAL 14:00:31.457197] [Gtk] gtk_box_pack: assertion '_gtk_widget_get_parent (child) == NULL' failed
[FATAL 14:00:31.587410] [Gtk] gtk_widget_set_no_show_all: assertion 'GTK_IS_WIDGET (widget)' failed
[FATAL 14:00:31.587497] [Gtk] gtk_widget_set_visible: assertion 'GTK_IS_WIDGET (widget)' failed
[WARNING 14:00:31.698957] [Gtk] Attempting to add a widget with type AyatanaCompatibilityIndicatorButton to a container of type GtkRevealer, but the widget is already inside a container of type GtkRevealer, please remove the widget from its existing container first.
[FATAL 14:00:32.067967] Manager.vala:61: Erreur lors de l'appel de StartServiceByName pour org.bluez : GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.systemd1.NoSuchUnit: Unit dbus-org.bluez.service not found.
[19:00:33.193341 Warning] [DesktopFileInfo] Unable to create AppInfo
[19:00:33.260197 Warning] [DesktopFileInfo] Unable to create AppInfo
[19:00:33.329039 Warning] [DesktopFileInfo] Unable to get exec for Autre
[19:00:33.396415 Warning] [DesktopFileInfo] Unable to create AppInfo
[19:00:33.396663 Warning] [DesktopFileInfo] Unable to create AppInfo
[19:00:33.399868 Warning] [DesktopFileInfo] Unable to create AppInfo
[19:00:33.404251 Warning] [DesktopFileInfo] Unable to create AppInfo
[19:00:33.404573 Warning] [DesktopFileInfo] Unable to create AppInfo
[19:00:33.404870 Warning] [DesktopFileInfo] Unable to create AppInfo
[19:00:33.409705 Warning] [DesktopFileInfo] Unable to create AppInfo
[19:00:33.411645 Warning] [DesktopFileInfo] Unable to create AppInfo
[19:00:33.412933 Warning] [DesktopFileInfo] Unable to create AppInfo
[19:00:33.414528 Warning] [DesktopFileInfo] Unable to create AppInfo
[19:00:33.418021 Warning] [DesktopFileInfo] Unable to create AppInfo
[19:00:33.424695 Warning] [DesktopFileInfo] Unable to create AppInfo
[19:00:38.748465 Info] Tweaks.vala:307: Activating Tweak plug
[19:00:40.266041 Warning] PlankSettings.vala:204: Le fichier de clés contient la clé « Monitor » dans le groupe « PlankDockPreferences » qui a une valeur impossible à interpréter.
```

Any suggestions ?

Comment: Same problem here! Any Solution?

Answer (score 0):

Try login as guest to clarify if it's an user error.